# Expdp partitioned table, Impdp Into non-partitioned table same structure

Tags: oracle, partitioning, oracle-19c

I have a partitioned table X in my production database.

I want to **expdp** it from production & **impdp** the same table X with data to my test database.

As I have a standard license in the test database, the partitioning feature is not available.

Any advice on how I can move the table structure/ data seamlessly.

Note that I have a list of tables with above issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PARTITION_OPTIONS](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sutil/datapump-import-utility.html#GUID-0271FAC1-3238-49AD-B317-7A018D359740)

> A value of MERGE combines all partitions and subpartitions into one
> table.
>
> Example
>
> The following example assumes that the sh.sales table has been
> exported into a dump file named sales.dmp. It uses the merge option to
> merge all the partitions in sh.sales into one non-partitioned table in
> scott schema.

```
impdp system TABLES=sh.sales PARTITION_OPTIONS=MERGE  DIRECTORY=dpump_dir1 DUMPFILE=sales.dmp REMAP_SCHEMA=sh:scott
```